# How to enforce user to upload only specific file type in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I want to enforce user to upload only pdf files in Angular 7 this is part of my code.When i click the button which is "Select File" at the page it brings "PDF File" but also brings **"All Files"** i want to enforce user by javascript function or typescript function help me please :)

Typescript

```
  filesP2: File[] = [];
  lastInvalidsP2: any;
  sendableFormDataP2: FormData;
  httpEmitter: Subscription;
  httpEvent: HttpEvent<{}>;
  maxSize: any;
  lastFileAt: Date;
  isBelgeVisible: boolean = false;
  uploadedBelgeId: number = null;
```

HTML

```
<input style="margin: 0 auto;" ngfSelect type="file" [(files)]="filesP2" accept=".pdf" [maxSize]="maxSize" [(lastInvalids)]="lastInvalidsP2" (filesChange)="lastFileAt=getDate()"/>

<ngfFormData [files]="filesP2" postName="file" [(FormData)]="sendableFormDataP2"></ngfFormData>
```

Comment: that's not possible, using the 'accept' is as close as you can get. After a file has been selected, you should check if it's the right file type. And even after that you should do some backend validation as well

Comment: That's ok but even user select "All Files" option and want to upload another file type like ".txt or .docx" etc. there must be error like "This is not a PDF file" I just want to function it backend but how?

Comment: you can split file name on basis of `.` and then check file extension that is pdf or not and can decide further more actions.

Comment: @FarhatZaman Can u give an example please ?

Comment: which npm package you are using for file uploading. can you provide me a link?

Comment: @FarhatZaman Never use a file-extension alone to filter uploads, otherwise someone can just rename `nastyVirus.exe` to `totallyNotAVirus.pdf`.

Comment: @Dai yes you are right.files can be rename and in that case he should validate file type on server side.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using reactive forms you can create custom validator

```js
import {
  FormControl
} from '@angular/forms';

export function requiredFileType(expectedFormats: string[]) {
  return function(control: FormControl) {
    const files = control.value;
    if (files) {
      const hasOtherType = files.some(file => {
        const splitParts = file.name.split('.');
        const extension = splitParts[splitParts.length - 1].toLowerCase();

        return 'pdf' != extension.toLowerCase();
      });
      if (hasOtherType) {
        return {
          requiredFileType: 'Wrong file type. Only pdf type supported.'
        };
      }
    }


    return null;
  };
}

//usage in angular forms
File: new FormControl({
  value: null,
  disabled: true
}, [Validators.required, requiredFileType(['xlsx', 'xlsm'])])
```